# Downloading file from Azure does not download full file, same works fine in local

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

We are using Azure to store our files and when we upload\download files, it uses Azure emulator where everything works fine and downloads the files with full size.

But we observed an issue in which files are not getting downloaded fully when we try to download it in our stage environment which uses Azure.

Download code is as below:

```
CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = await GetContainerAsync(tenantId);
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileId);

            return await blockBlob.DownloadRangeToByteArrayAsync(target, index, offset, length);
```

And from API we do below:

```
var read = await _fileStorageService.DownloadRangeToByteArrayAsync(id, buffer, 0, offset, dataToRead > bufferSize ? bufferSize : dataToRead);
                            offset += read;
                            dataToRead -= read;

                            await Response.Body.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);
                            await Response.Body.FlushAsync();
```

What we are doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing the wrong length to method and it is downloading the file up to that length only. If you want to download the whole file , you should you this:

```
CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = await GetContainerAsync(tenantId);
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileId);
return await blockBlob.DownloadToByteArrayAsync(target, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks but we are reading in chunks as the file might be big. I did not mean to download whole file at once, I meant it does not download whole file at all, works fine in local.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. You need to do a `FetchAttributesAsync` on the blob to get the initial size of the byte array. If you want to download in chunks, just do multiple `DownloadToByteArrayAsync` calls with a different index.

```
 public async Task<byte[]> GetFile(string container, string directory, string blobName)
             {
                 CloudBlobContainer cloudContainer = client.GetContainerReference(container);
                 CloudBlobDirectory cloudDirectory = cloudContainer.GetDirectoryReference(directory);
                 CloudBlockBlob blob = cloudDirectory.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

                 await blob.FetchAttributesAsync();
                 long fileByteLength = blob.Properties.Length;
                 byte[] fileContent = new byte[fileByteLength];
                 for (int i = 0; i < fileByteLength; i++)
                 {
                     fileContent[i] = 0x20;
                 }
                 await blob.DownloadToByteArrayAsync(fileContent, 0);
                 return fileContent;
             }
```